# Get state from componentDidMount fails in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm trying to get the **region** state from componentDidMount (or render) function, but it fails. Do you know why?

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {

  super(props);

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.region = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.005,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        longitudeDelta: 0.005,
      }
      console.log("location from constructor:", this.region);
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 2000}
  );

  this.state = {
    region: this.region
  }

}

componentDidMount() {

  console.log("location from componentDidMount:", this.state.region);

}
```

Here are my logs:

```
location from componentDidMount: undefined

location from constructor: Object {latitude: 48.8732, latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitude: 2.402855, longitudeDelta: 0.005}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#getcurrentposition) is an asynchronous function. The time taken for asynchronous functions to complete and call appropriate success or failure callbacks  is indeterminate. It is not guaranteed to occur before the componentDidMount call.